# Python 3, list.append not working

Tags: python, list, append

New here and have been hunting around for the answer to this question. Working on a Project Euler question and attempting to add values of a function to a list using list.append, however nothing is being added to the list and I'm unsure why. Any help appreciated.

```
    import math
    import logging
    %config Application.log_level="INFO"

    input = 600851475143
    factlist = []

    def factors(i):
        for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(input)) + 1):
            if(input%i == 0):
                factlist.append()
                print(i)
```

Have tried defining the list inside and outside of the loop but to no avail.

Comment: First, the indentation is wrong: the `if` statement should be more indented than `for`, and the `for` more than `def`

Comment: Moreover: are you actually calling the function somewhere?

Comment: Hi louis, yes thats how I have it formatted, it just hasn't carried over to here. I call the function further in.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you need to actually call the function somewhere, and you also need to give an argument to `append` :

```
import math
import logging
%config Application.log_level="INFO"

input_ = 600851475143

def factors(input_):
    factlist = []
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(input_)) + 1):
        if(input_%i == 0):
            factlist.append(i)

factlist = factors(input_)
```

Moreover, don't use the name `input` for a variable since it's a Python function.

Comment: ahhhh, right I see, so in order for the function to actually output any data I need to call it separately and not just "run" the code where I define the factor! Understood :) Thanks indeed guys! I have never done any real coding before so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the element you want to append as a parameter to `append`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the right argument:

```
if(input%i == 0):
    factlist.append(i) #<- i added
    print(i)
```

And of course, you need to call your function somewhere

Comment: Hi Nils. I have tried this, however when I "print" the list it still contains no values.

Comment: Then you probably never call your function.